# Make div move when div above getting bigger

Tags: jquery, html, position, toggle

I have a text and under a button to toggle some icons. Under the text there is a div for the pagination and I've set a top margin to put it in the right place under the text. I've done that because I don't know why even if it is in the html just after the text, with no values it's on the left corner of the main container just like it was absolute and the container was relative?

The problem is when I toggle the icons, the description div overflows the pagination div. I don't know how to make it move lower when it does that.

Any ideas? Thank you :)

```js
// Show hide on click

    function showNavi(){
        $("#navigationin").toggle('slow','swing');
      $('#chevron').toggleClass('rotate180');
      $('.rainbow').toggleClass('changecolor')
    };
// Scroll to top
 //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
   $('.scrolltotop').fadeIn();
  } else {
   $('.scrolltotop').fadeOut();
  }
 });
 
 //Click event to scroll to top
 $('.scrolltotop').click(function(){
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
  return false;
 });

// Random color
function entryOver(classnm) {
    $(classnm).css('border-color',randomColor({
   luminosity: 'bright',
   format: 'hsl' 
}))
};
function notEntryOver(classnm) {
    $(classnm).css('border-color',"#dadada")
};

// Icons drop down
function iconsFunction() {
  $("#mainicons").toggle(function(){ $(this).animate({height:250},200); },function(){ $(this).animate({height:0},200); });
  $('#avatar i').toggleClass('rotateavatar');
};

  $( function() {
    $( ".about" ).draggable({cursor: "move"});
  } );
```

```css
a{
  text-decoration:none
}
/*-- PAGINATION --*/

.pagination {
  margin-top:90%;
  text-align:center
}
   
.pagination a {
margin-bottom:10px;
color:#fff;
background-color:#bababa;
display: inline-block;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 100%;
line-height: 20px;
    margin-left:5px;
}
   
.pagination a:hover {
color:#58acfa;
background:#fff;
}

.current_page{
  margin-bottom:10px;
    color:{color:Text};
    padding:4px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #58acfa;
    margin-left:5px
}


  /*------ MENU -----*/
  .about{
    cursor:move;
    z-index:1000;
    position:fixed;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    left:100px;
    top:60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #bababa;
    background:white;
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: .5s ease;
    -o-transition: .5s ease;
    transition: .5s ease;
  }


  /* Main icons */

  #mainicons {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .7s ease;
    -o-transition: all .7s ease;
    transition: all .7s ease;
  }

#mainicons>a {
margin-top: 10px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

  #mainicons i {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #bababa;
    border-radius:100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
  }

  #mainicons i:hover {
      background:#fff;
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  
  #mainicons .fa-home:hover{
      color:red;
  }
  #mainicons .fa-comment:hover{
      color:#fe9a2e;
  }
  #mainicons .fa-download:hover{
      color:#37ce00;
  }
  #mainicons .fa-address-card:hover{
      color:#58acfa;
  }

  /* Avatar */

  #avatar {
    position:absolute;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:10px 0 0 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index:10;
  }

  #avatar img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius:100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
  }
  
  #avatar i{
      position:absolute;
      left:0;
      width:101%;
      height:101%;
      border-radius:100%;
      font-size:15px;
      line-height:50px;
      text-align:center;
      color:#bababa;
      opacity:0;
      background:#fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
  }
  
  #avatar:hover i{
      opacity:1;
  }
  
  .rotateavatar{
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);      
  }
  /* Description */

  #description {
    position: absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:10px 0 0 90px;
    color: #000;
    background: #dadada;
    padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px;
    width:180px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 18px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }
  
  #description:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 18px 18px 18px 0;
border-color: transparent #fff;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
left: -18px;
top: 10px;
}

  .rainbow {
      position:absolute;
      width:200%;
      height:2px;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      opacity:0.5;
    border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) );
  background-image: gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) );
     -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    transition: all 0.7s ease;  
}

.rainbow.changecolor{
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
  
  /* Search box */

  #search {
    margin:10px auto 10px auto;
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #404040;
    background: #fff;
    border:1px solid black;
  }
  
  #search .fa-search{
      font-size:12px!important;
      float:right;
      margin-right:5px;
      line-height:25px;
  }

  /* Navigation */

#description .fa-chevron-down{
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:12px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
#description .fa-chevron-down:hover{
    color:#58acfa;
}
.rotate180{
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);  
}

#navigationin i {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #404040!important;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin:5px 6px 5px 6px;
    padding:3px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
  }
  #navigationin i:hover {
-webkit-transform : rotate(360deg);
-moz-transform : rotate(360deg);
-ms-transform : rotate(360deg);
-o-transform : rotate(360deg);
transform : rotate(360deg);
  }
   #navigationin .fa-question-circle:hover{
      color:red!important;
  }
  #navigationin .fa-link:hover{
      color:#fe9a2e!important;
  }
  #navigationin .fa-music:hover{
      color:#ffde07!important;
  }
  #navigationin .fa-user-circle-o:hover{
      color:#37ce00!important;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/randomcolor/0.5.2/randomColor.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<div class="about" onmouseover="entryOver(this)" onmouseout="notEntryOver(this)">

<div id="mainicons" hidden>
<a href="/" title="home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
<a href="/ask" title="contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i></a>
<a href="/submit" title="sumbit"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
<a href="/about" title="about"><i class="fa fa-address-card"></i></a>
</div>
<!--End mainicons-->


<div id="avatar" onclick="iconsFunction(this)"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/5c231601a0942f139489cca966931eef/4cxodkk/AOSorhvq1/tumblr_static_dpxyh4zatkgsocg4888kg8wg8.png"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></div>

<div id="description">
<span class="rainbow"></span>
<p>Welcome to <font color="#58acfa">actorsblog</font>!</p>
<p>Here you will find all sorts of fandom <b>pictures</b>, <b>icons</b> and <b>edits</b>!</p>
<p>If you have a question, a  request or a post to submit, <b>click the avatar</b>!</p>
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" id="chevron" onclick="showNavi()"></i>
      <div id="navigationin" hidden>
    <center>
    <a href="{text:Link One Url}" title="{text:Link One Title}"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></a>
    <a href="{text:Link Two Url}" title="{text:Link Two Title}"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
    <a href="{text:Link Three Url}" title="{text:Link Three Title}"><i class="fa fa-music"></i></a>
    <a href="{text:Link Four Url}" title="{text:Link Four Title}"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i></a>
    </center>
    </div>
    <!--End navigationin-->
    <div id="search">
    <form action="/search" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="q" value="SEARCH" style="position:absolute; width:120px;     line-height:25px; padding-left:10px; font-family:{select:Body font}; font-size: 12px;      background:transparent; border:1px solid transparent; color:"#404040";"/>
    <i class="fa fa-search" type="submit"></i>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="pagination">
<a href="{PreviousPage}">←</a>

<span class="current_page">1</span>

<a class="jump_page" href="{URL}">2</a>

<a href="{NextPage}">→</a>

</div>
<!--End pager-->

</div><!--End about-->
```

Comment: Why don't you try to get the current margin top value of .pagination in jquery and add 31px to and set to it?

Comment: Yes I thought about that @PradeepSambandam but isn't there a way when jquery does it automatically? Like for example the description's height increased by itself

Comment: Yes Actually the description's height increases, But the absolute position of description does not move the pagination div down.

Comment: So if I change position:absolute to something else maybe it will work? @PradeepSambandam

Comment: Yes changing from position absolute to relative will work and you should also change the margin-top 90% to 10px like that.

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly (at first I didn't know you were talking about the description position)! @PradeepSambandam

Comment: Glad to hear that worked! Thanks, I have posted that as an answer, Please accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Following should work!

Change the position of #desription from position absolute to relative and should also change the margin-top of .pagination from 90% to 10px like that.

Comment: Thanks again, while we're at it do you think I could ask you another question about the same project?

Comment: No Problem, What's your another question?

Comment: Do you know why the jquery toggle function isn't working properly on the #mainicons div please?

Comment: Instead of toggling display, Can you try toggling height of the div?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: $("#mainicons").toggle(function(){
    $(this).animate({height:250},200);
  },function(){
    $(this).animate({height:0},200);
  });

Comment: Looks like it's doing the same thing :x

Comment: I think the issue is because of the position absolute of #mainicons, it should work fine with your earlier jquery code itself

Comment: So once again if I change the position of the #mainicons it will work?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like my previous answer was not clear. I have created a JSFiddle. Since Stack Overflow isn't allowing me to add Fiddle link here. I'll add it in the comment section. https:// jsfiddle.net/soz9zhby/2/

I hope this solves your issue. Please let me know if have any other issues.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately this didn't work :/

Comment: If you are using fixed then it may not work. Because fixed position makes the content to stay still at a fixed position. Hence it may overlap.

Comment: One option that you have is creating a fixed div. Followed by a relative position child div. Further add two child div's to it. make to first child overflow: auto. And the second child should have position:absolute; bottom:0. Give minimum height to relative div if necessary.